# how do I delete reverse duplicates from a table

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

I have a table with related values. Sometimes there are records with the reverse relation. I want to delete those but dont know how to handle this. eg:
table with two columns (KOL1 & KOL2):

```
A-B
A-C
A-D
A-E
B-C
B-E
F-G
C-A
C-D
```

In the example above C-A is the record I want deleted because it is the reverse record of A-C already in the list.
How can I do this using access QUERIES?

Answer (score 1):

ok,I think this does the job

SELECT E1, E2
FROM Table1
WHERE E1<=E2
UNION
SELECT E2, E1
FROM Table1
WHERE E1>E2

Comment: Can you elaborate ? How did it work ?